# Recursive Firebase Firestore Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have 4 firestore collections:

1. `users/{userId}` which I allow access only for the same use - `request.auth.uid == userId`
2. `organizations/{organizationId}` which I allow access for users of that organization - `exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/organizations/{organizationId}/users/$(request.auth.uid))`

So far, easy rules. The following collections have references to either a user, or an organization, and best case scenario I would like to just tell firestore: `hasAccess(someReference, read)`.

3. `notifications` which have a `ref` for who to notify, which can be either `users/{userId}` or `organizations/{organizationId}` which I allow access if it is a reference to the user or to an organization the user is a member of (a combination of the previous two rules)
4. `accounts` which have an array of organization `ref`, and I would like the rule to be like: `resource.data.organizations.any(organization => hasAccess(organizationRef, read))`

#### Questions:

1. Is there a way to ask firebase to match the new reference and return if the user has access to it?
2. Is there a way to treat an array like in my 4th collection, where I want to have an "any" operation?

#### Edit:

It is recursive because I want when a collection is matched, to ask about another collection rules, which can ask about another, etc.. (`hasAccess`)

#### Edit 2:

One workaround is to make a function `canAccess` which I can call recursively,  such that for any path I can do `canAccess(request.path);`.

BUT "Error saving rules - Line 5: Recursive call is not allowed."